# Is there any difference between the question "why would anyone do that" and "why would anyone have done that"?

Tags: difference, questions, conditionals

Could there if there is any difference between the question *why would anyone do that* and *why would anyone have done that*? For example:

> Sara says somebody has stolen her pen. That's insanity. **Why would anyone do that**?
>
> Sara says somebody has stolen her pen. That's insanity. **Why would anyone have done that**?

Comment: Why don't you tell us? You constantly pose these questions without making any effort.

Comment: @Lambie: I've got the most extensive English grammar books. By now, I would say, I know them inside out because I always use them for reference. As good as they are, I couldn't find the answer to the question I posted.

Comment: One is past conditional and one is present conditional. Your books don't have that?

Comment: @Lambie: Yes, they do have them, but in the context I provided I can't see a clear distinction between them.

Comment: Why would anyone ask a question like this? [I ask now.] VERSUS Why would anyone have asked a question like this? [I ask about the past, for example, your other questions like this one.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both mean essentially the same thing. However there is a subtle difference in the implicit emphasis, at least as I read them:

1. Why would anyone **DO** that?

This is almost a philosophical and moral question. Why would anyone **DO** that? I can't imagine the sociopathic state of mind to commit this heinous act.

2. **WHY** would anyone have done **THAT**?

This is more a question about the specific act. You're leaving something out. I don't believe the story. It doesn't make sense. Maybe there was a misunderstanding.